# Question about asymptotic integral expansion. Reference?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I need to compute a series expansion in $\epsilon$ (at least to second order) of integrals like

$$g(\epsilon):=\int_0^\epsilon f(\epsilon,v)\, dv,$$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, where the functions in question are very complicated. (Too complicated, in my opinion, to express as Taylor series themselves.)

Does anyone have a reference for such things?  I have tried naively expanding around $0$, <strike>but some of the derivatives blow up there, so I haven't been able to reconcile terms like $g''(0)$ which don't exist.</strike>

(The derivatives at $\epsilon=0$ are functions of $v$. But, they are not integrable on $[0,\epsilon]$)

Thanks.

EDIT:  per request, here is one such $f$:

[image]

Note that we have $|v|<\epsilon$ and $\epsilon>0$ small.

EDIT #2:  Would still like a reference for the theory of integral expansions if someone has one they like.

Comment: Remember that under some assumptions, $$g'(\epsilon) = f(\epsilon, \epsilon) + \int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{d}{d \epsilon} f(\epsilon, v) dv$$ So you could calculate $g'(0)$ yourself and do the same thing for the second derivative.
Is this of any help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Yes, you are right, and that is what I have been doing so far.  My issue is that the second derivative of $f$ wrt $\epsilon$ goes to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, so I don't know if it's valid for me to write something like 

$$g(\epsilon) = f(0,0)\epsilon + (\epsilon^2/2)(f_v(0,0) + 2f_\epsilon(0,0)) + O(\epsilon^3)$$

Comment: Then the desired expansion may not exist. Have you tried to numerically compute the derivatives?

Comment: Can I see $f$'s expression?

Comment: Well, that's horrible lol. Anyway, I'll tell you what I was thinking: even if $f''$ goes to infinity, you may find a function g which is integrable in a right neighbourhood of 0 and such that $f(\epsilon, v) \leq g(v)$ for every $\epsilon$ in that neighbourhood. In that case, $\int_0^{\epsilon} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \epsilon^2} f(\epsilon, v) \, dv \to 0$.
I don't have time to try this right now.

Comment: Good thought, I will look into this.  Thanks!

Comment: @martycohen thanks for your thoughts as well.  It seems to me that it's just an ugly composition of smooth functions, so \textit{I think} it should be infinitely differentiable in a nbd of $0$.  But of course I did not prove this.

Comment: One thing further I just realized, is that the second derivative of $f$ in epsilon at $\epsilon=0$ is a well defined function of $v$, but it's nonintegrable around 0.  In particular, I still can't compute $f_{\epsilon\epsilon$(0,0)$.